# Aptanta Studio 3 doesn't load

Tags: aptana3

My Aptana Studio 3 doesn't start every time. At the moment I'm not able to work with cause everytime i start the application the IDE freezes and I get "No Response" and have to close it.

In the Past I experienced some problems with personal folders including special characters (in my case "ä"). I successfully renamed the windows user and reinstalled aptana, so I don't know if this is still the problem or something else.

below you can find my log file.

The line "Cannot run program "ruby" (data not found) could be a hint? is it possible to deactivate ruby via config e.g.? I don't need it.

---

```
!SESSION 2013-02-04 08:25:42.610 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.3.1.201212171919
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY com.aptana.ruby.core 4 0 2013-02-04 08:25:58.244
!MESSAGE Cannot run program "ruby": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-02-04 08:26:21.408
!MESSAGE While loading class "org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.Preferences", thread "Thread[Worker-14,5,main]" timed out waiting (5005ms) for thread "Thread[main,6,main]" to finish starting bundle "org.eclipse.debug.core_3.7.1.v20111129-2031 [167]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Worker-14,5,main]" is proceeding but "org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.Preferences" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core_3.7.1.v20111129-2031.jar" by thread "main".
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin$1.saving(DebugPlugin.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.executeLifecycle(SaveManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager$1.run(SaveManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.broadcastLifecycle(SaveManager.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1130)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1109)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.DelayedSnapshotJob.run(DelayedSnapshotJob.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    ... 22 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin$1.saving(DebugPlugin.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.executeLifecycle(SaveManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager$1.run(SaveManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.broadcastLifecycle(SaveManager.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1130)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1109)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.DelayedSnapshotJob.run(DelayedSnapshotJob.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar error while developing PHP code.  When I shutdown Aptana I was in the Team Synchronization View (I'm using Subversion via Subclipse).  When I restarted Aptana, I was still in the Team Sync View and the IDE was completely unresponsive.

I was able to "solve" this problem by:

mv ~/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/.metadata  ~/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/.metadata_old

and restarting Aptana.  I then was forced to import my existing PHP project back into Aptana.

I have no idea what the problem was or why this worked.